# Order stacked barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I didn't find anwser to my question on Stack Overflow so I allowed myself to write this one. I would like to make ordered stacked barplot (with two or more grouping/filling variables) so I wrote code which you can find below.

I wonder whether it is posible to do it simpler/inside ggplot function without creating ordered factor? I would be very grateful for all hints.

Here is my code

```
p<-ggplot(data=gf18l, aes(x=variable,y=valuep,fill=ID)) +
  geom_bar(position='stack',stat='identity')

varorder<-gf18l[order(gf18l$ID,gf18l$valuep), ]
varorder<-varorder[varorder$ID==1,'variable']
gf18l$variable<-factor(as.character(gf18l$variable),
                       levels=varorder,
                       labels=varorder,
                       ordered=T)
p %+% gf18l + coord_flip()
```

and here is my data

```
gf18l<-structure(list(ID = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", 
        "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", 
        "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", 
        "1", "2", "1", "2"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                   3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
                   11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
                   17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("GF18A_01", "GF18A_02", 
                             "GF18A_03", "GF18A_04", "GF18A_05", "GF18A_06", "GF18A_07", "GF18A_08", "GF18A_09", "GF18A_10", "GF18A_11", "GF18A_12", "GF18A_13", "GF18A_14", 
"GF18A_15", "GF18A_16", "GF18A_17", "GF18A_18", "GF18A_19"), class = "factor"), 
       value = c(11336L, 1007L, 2691L, 9629L, 7192L, 5136L, 7740L, 
        4581L, 8794L, 3536L, 7014L, 5317L, 1991L, 10323L, 529L, 11777L, 
        5685L, 6649L, 5465L, 6869L, 906L, 11406L, 357L, 11964L, 7828L, 
        4510L, 7809L, 4525L, 6269L, 6061L, 126L, 12186L, 1533L, 10782L, 
        9719L, 2601L, 989L, 11285L), valuep = c(0.918415296119258, 
                  0.0815847038807421, 0.218425324675325, 0.781574675324675, 
                  0.583387410772226, 0.416612589227774, 0.628195763330898, 
                  0.371804236669102, 0.713219789132198, 0.286780210867802, 
                  0.568810315465088, 0.431189684534912, 0.161685885983434, 
                  0.838314114016567, 0.042987160734601, 0.957012839265399, 
                  0.460921031295606, 0.539078968704394, 0.443084157613102, 
                  0.556915842386898, 0.0735867446393762, 0.926413255360624, 
                  0.0289749208668128, 0.971025079133187, 0.634462635759442, 
                  0.365537364240558, 0.633127939030323, 0.366872060969677, 
                  0.508434712084347, 0.491565287915653, 0.010233918128655, 
                  0.989766081871345, 0.124482338611449, 0.875517661388551, 
                  0.78887987012987, 0.21112012987013, 0.080576829069578, 0.919423170930422
        )), .Names = c("ID", "variable", "value", "valuep"), row.names = c(NA, 
                           -38L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `limits` argument within the `scale_x_discrete` function from `ggplot2` to order your bars.

```
ggplot(data=gf18l, aes(x=variable,y=valuep,fill=ID)) +
  geom_bar(position='stack',stat='identity') + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=with(gf18l, variable[ID==1][order(valuep[ID==1])])) + 
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Thanks! Would it be flexible for more than two gruping variables?

Comment: I am not sure how you would like to sort more your bars with more than 2 groups. But if you know, which order you want the bars to be in, then you can specify this order in limits. It is essentially the same thing that you did with the ordered variable, so it is no more and no less flexible.